# Error unknown function in q_0 as in q_0

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
  \node[state,initial] (q_0,q_2) {$q_0,q_2$};
  \node[state] (q_1)   [above right=of q_0,q_2] {$q_1$};
  \node[state] (q_3)   [right=of q_1] {$q_3$};
  \node[state,accepting] (q_4) [below right=of q_0,q_2] {$q_4$};
  \path[->] (q_0,q_2) edge node {a} (q_1)
            (q_0) edge node {b} (q_2)
            (q_1) edge [loop above] node {a} (q_1)
            (q_1) edge  node {b} (q_3)
            (q_3) edge [bend right=40] node {a} (q_1)
            (q_3) edge node {b} (q_4)
            (q_4) edge node {b} (q_2)
            (q_4) edge node {a} (q_1);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Unknown function in 'q_0'

Comment: Are you allowed to use underscores there? Sorry, i am not experienced with TikZ and you didn't providde compilable code.

Comment: Can I write q0,q2 a single state?

Comment: Don't know, have you tried?

Comment: You have asked this question before: [Math Error :Unknown function 'q\_1'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266253/math-error-unknown-function-q-1)

Answer (score 4):

To quote the manual:

> Your node name should not
>   contain any punctuation like a dot, a comma, or a colon since these are used to detect what kind
>   of coordinate you mean when you reference a node.

The quote is taken from the description of the `name` key in section 17.2.1 *Syntax of the Node Command*, bottom of page 215, top of page 216. (In the manual for TikZ 3.0.1a, dated August 29 2015.)

Hence, you cannot use `q_0,q_2` as a node name, but `q_0q_2` works fine. You also need to specify the nodes named `q_0` and `q_2`.
I commented the lines using those two node names below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
  \node[state,initial] (q_0q_2)  {$q_0,q_2$};
  \node[state] (q_1)   [above right=of q_0q_2] {$q_1$};
  \node[state] (q_3)   [right=of q_1] {$q_3$};
  \node[state,accepting] (q_4) [below right=of q_0q_2] {$q_4$};
  \path[->] (q_0q_2) edge node {a} (q_1)
           % (q_0) edge node {b} (q_2)
            (q_1) edge [loop above] node {a} (q_1)
            (q_1) edge  node {b} (q_3)
            (q_3) edge [bend right=40] node[swap] {a} (q_1)
            (q_3) edge node {b} (q_4)
           % (q_4) edge node {b} (q_2)
            (q_4) edge node {a} (q_1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]